# Can somebody from the EU get an Australian business number to register a COM.AU domain?

Tags: domains, registration

I need a help with .com.au domain registration. I live in EU, so I’m not a citizen of Australia. In case to register this address, I need an Australian business number (ABN). I’m going to develop a simple website (without any kind of sales) and monetize it with Google Adsense. So, is it possible to get an ABN for a website like that and register .com.au address?

Answer (score 5):

To get an ABN without having an Australian tax file number (TFN), you must provide:

> proof of identity documents and a statement of your business activities in Australia.
>
> *[ABN for businesses outside Australia - Australian Business Register](https://abr.gov.au/for-business,-super-funds---charities/applying-for-an-abn/abn-for-businesses-outside-australia/)*

So if you are not living in Australia, not an Australian citizen and not running a business in Australia, you are out of luck in getting a `.com.au` domain.

Comment: Then maybe you know is there is a possibility of third party service for registration?

Comment: @MykolasK I don't know of any personally. There may or may not be a viable loophole.

Comment: They are very strict on the .com.au registration. I'm from Australian and my sister had one for her shop, and it was still a pita for her to get it sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

A foreign company can register a .com.au in Australia if it has eligibility. One way to obtain the right to apply for a .com.au is to obtain a trade mark. Once you file for the trade mark application you can apply for the domain name.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are basically trying to get around registry policies as you are not eligible plain and simple.

The registry website at https://www.auda.org.au/industry-information/au-domains/ states for `com.au`:

> For commercial entities, such as companies (with ACN as registered
>   through ASIC), and businesses (registered with state governments).

You are neither a commercial entity nor a business based on your description, so you are not eligible to get a `com.au`.

If you really want it, you will need to ask someone else, that is eligible, to register it on your behalf. With a lot of caveats on that operation, besides the cost. This is basically called a "proxy" service and is allowed or not, depending on the TLD. Many registrars provide this service, so contact your trusted one and ask him what he offers for `.com.au` domains. Any question like yours should start at a registrar. Or you can also ask the registry directly and state your case. But most of the time any competent registrar should be able to give you a tailored answer based on your specific situation.